# how to create wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_style

Tags: wordpress

Below code shows my script file included in `footer.php`, I need to convert HTML theme to WordPress theme. the below code I want to write a function of functions.php. so how can I create `wp_register_script`, and `wp_enqueue_script`??

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hippo-offcanvas.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.inview.min.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.stellar.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.countTo.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/classie.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/selectFx.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js'; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: It's really easy, just read the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) please. Also, take a look at the [examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-274).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have activated ***child theme*** then use `get_template_directory_uri()` functions.

If you have activated ***parent theme*** then use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` functions.

---

[**get_template_directory_uri**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) will always refer to the parent theme folder for assets.

[**get_stylesheet_directory_uri**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) will refer to the "current" theme folder for assets (which could be the parent or the child, depending on where it is called).

**Child theme example:**  [**`wp_register_script`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Function_Reference/wp_register_script)

```
wp_register_script( 'my_child_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

**Parent theme Example** [**`wp_register_script`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Function_Reference/wp_register_script)

```
wp_register_script( 'my_parent_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

---

### Final example:-

[**`wp_enqueue_scripts`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_and_register_my_scripts' );

function enqueue_and_register_my_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'my_child_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_child_script' );
}
```

Comment: i really apreciate for your valuable answer, thank you somuch

Answer (score 1):

You can register them like this:

```
define( 'THEME_VERSION', '1.1.20170718' );    
function yourtheme_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'yourtheme-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), THEME_VERSION, true );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourtheme_scripts' );
```

You can enqueue as many scripts and styles as you like in that function